# Why can i not have my label say "The Adventure of -character name-"

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a function which returns the user input. However, I cannot use that user input in a sentence. After the first couple of comments, I realise it's maybe because of my label being created before the user can input any value.

I am not sure how to fix this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
class NamePage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        self.controller = controller
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Please type the 
                         name you want your character to have",
                         width=127, height=30,
                         font=font_remaining, bd=1,
                         relief="solid", anchor=CENTER)
        label.grid(row=1, column=1, pady=10, padx=10)
        button_continue = tk.Button(self, width=40, height=3, bd=1 
                                    relief="solid",
                                    font=font_button, text="Continue", 
                                    command=lambda: value())
        button_continue.place(x=425, y=500)
        entry1 = tk.Entry(self, 
                           textvariable=self.controller.shared_data["name"])
        entry1.place(x=425, y=400)
        entry1.config(width=67)

        def value():
            value1 = self.controller.shared_data["name"].get()
            print(value1)
            controller.show_frame(TitlePage)

class TitlePage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        self.controller = controller
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, bg=background_options, text="The Adventure of 
                         " 
                         + 
                         self.value_name(), width=127, height=30,
                         font=font_title, bd=1,
                         relief="solid", anchor=CENTER)
        label.grid(row=1, column=1, pady=10, padx=10)


    def value_name(self):
        value2 = self.controller.shared_data["name"].get()
        input_name = value2
        print(input_name)
        return input_name

app = firstwindow()
app.mainloop()
```

user inputs John

Expected results = The Adventure of John

actual results = The Adventure of

Comment: Wild guess: the `label = ...` line executes before you call `mainloop`, so there's no way the user could possibly have typed anything into the `self.controller.shared_data["name"]` textbox yet. It correctly sees that the box contains no text, and sets the label accordingly.

Comment: I have checked my full program and the mainloop runs first then the label. I appreciate your input though.

Comment: Please show a [mcve]. The code you posted absolutely will work, assuming that `self.controller.shared_data["name"]` has been defined, and the user has had a chance to enter something before this function is called. My guess is, you're creating the label before the user has a chance to input any data just like @Kevin says.

Comment: @BryanOakley, I have added more code and after reviewing the code again, I agree with both of you. However, I am not quite sure how to fix it. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest fix is to make a `StringVar` for your label in `TitlePage`. Then when you switch frames after the initial input, set the new label directly:

```
class NamePage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        ...
        def value():
            value1 = self.controller.shared_data["name"].get()
            controller.frames[TitlePage].var.set(f"The Adventure of {value1}") #set new value here
            controller.show_frame(TitlePage)

class TitlePage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        self.controller = controller
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.var = StringVar() #create StringVar here
        label = tk.Label(self, bg=background_options, textvariable=self.var, #assign textvariable
                         width=127, height=30, font=font_title, bd=1,
                         relief="solid", anchor=CENTER)
        ...
```